# Google Analytics 4 - persistent values are not sent when configured using the 'set' command

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to configure an event parameter that will be sent automatically with every event I send to GA4.
Including the page_view event and all other "Automatically collected events".

This is my setup configuration:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    
    gtag('js', new Date());

    // Doesn't work!!
    gtag('set', {
      'parameter_key': 'parameter_value'
    });

    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX');    
</script>
```

When I'm using the `set` command, the `param_key` event parameter is not sent with any event. It's totally ignored.
However, when I move this object into the `config` command, it does work:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    
    gtag('js', new Date());

    // Works!
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX', {
      'parameter_key': 'parameter_value'
    });
</script>
```

I want to use the `set` command because I have multiple properties, and I want this parameter to be used for all properties.

Anybody knows why it's not working and how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using pre-defined or custom ones? If custom, have they been defined in the GA4 config?

Comment: 1. These parameters are custom parameters. They are not defined anywhere on Google Analytics.
~~
2. In Google Analytics docs it says I can set persistent values either using the `config` command or the `set` command (in case I have multiple properties).
When I'm using the `set` command - it's not working.

Comment: Aside from using "set" you'll need to define them in the analytics config. Follow the documentation here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article